# How to make default value in the textarea change/autofill when the input text field is filled?

Tags: javascript, textarea

For example on input like this:

```html
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group my-2">
      <input class="form-control mx-2" type="text" placeholder="Customer Name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group mb-2">
      <input class="form-control mx-2" type="email" placeholder="Customer Email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group mb-2">
      <input class="form-control mx-2" type="text" placeholder="Customer pin">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group mb-2">
      <textarea class="form-control mx-2" rows="4">
Hi, {customer Name here}
Your Email is: {customer Email here}
Your Pin is:  {customer pin here}
      </textarea>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

- When the Customer Name input is entered: John Doe
- When the Customer Email input is entered: johndoe@mail.com
- When the Customer pin input is entered: 123

### Then the textarea value should become

```
Hi, John Doe
Your Email is: johndoe@mail.com
Your Pin is: 123
```

How would I autofill the textarea with the data that the user inputted?

Comment: Use jQuery or React or Angular or Vanilla JS. You can just get the value of each field and append it with a break in textarea. Do you know keyup, and append events of JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use JavaScript. It will build your complete textarea content from the inputted values whenever they are updated. Like this:

```js
// Input elements
var customerName = document.getElementById("customer-name");
var customerEmail = document.getElementById("customer-email");
var customerPin = document.getElementById("customer-pin");

// Output textarea
var customerInfo = document.getElementById("customer-info");

function updateTextareaContent(){
  customerInfo.value=`Hi, ${customerName.value||"(enter name)"}
Your Email is: ${customerEmail.value||"(enter email)"}
Your Pin is: ${customerPin.value||"(enter pin)"}`;
}

customerName.addEventListener("keydown", updateTextareaContent);
customerEmail.addEventListener("keydown", updateTextareaContent);
customerPin.addEventListener("keydown", updateTextareaContent);

customerName.addEventListener("keyup", updateTextareaContent);
customerEmail.addEventListener("keyup", updateTextareaContent);
customerPin.addEventListener("keyup", updateTextareaContent);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group my-2">
      <input class="form-control mx-2" type="text" placeholder="Customer Name" id="customer-name">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group mb-2">
      <input class="form-control mx-2" type="email" placeholder="Customer Email" id="customer-email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group mb-2">
      <input class="form-control mx-2" type="text" placeholder="Customer pin" id="customer-pin">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group mb-2">
      <textarea class="form-control mx-2" rows="4" id="customer-info">
Hi, (enter name)
Your Email is: (enter email)
Your Pin is: (enter pin)
      </textarea>
  </div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

(The snippet is a bit large so it is collapsed, click the arrow to open it)

This watches for changes in the text, and when those changes happen, it updates the textarea.

Here's some further reading in order to more better understand the code snippet:

- [Event Listeners](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) on w3schools
- [keydown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keydown_event) and [keyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keyup_event) events on MDN
- [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) on MDN

Comment: Extraordinary! Your answer is clean and easy to understand. Thanks you really saving my time :)

Comment: @MaruliDavin you're welcome! It's what we do here on Stack Overflow. I added some further reading resources in case you want to learn more about the topics used in the code snippet. Thank you :)